# Open iCloud in current Finder window with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, icloud

I'm trying to open iCloud in the current Finder window/tab. The below AppleScript works with any other folder.

How can I open iCloud in the current Finder window with AppleScript?

```
tell application "Finder"
    reopen
    activate
    set p to "~/Library/Mobile Documents/"
    set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file p
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script doesn't work because the Finder is not able to expand the tilde in POSIX paths.

This is an alternative with a relative path.

```
set userLibraryFolder to path to library folder from user domain
tell application "Finder"
    reopen
    activate
    set iCloudDriveFolder to folder "iCloud Drive" of folder "Mobile Documents" of userLibraryFolder
    set target of Finder window 1 to iCloudDriveFolder
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks but actually that doesn't work, it just highlights the 'Mobile Documents' folder in the library rather than showing me the iCloud folder

Comment: What do you mean with *iCloud folder*? Your script is going to open the `Mobile Documents` folder, too, and I just made your script working

Comment: This sets the path to Mobile Documents, but you then need to double click or type 'cmd + o' to open it.If this is the best possible option then I may need to settle on it (thanks) but ideally when the AppleScript is executed Finder would immediately show you the actual contents of the iCloud folder e.g. 'Desktop' 'Documents' etc.

Comment: To accomplish that you have to set the target to the folder `iCloud Drive`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer because this won't open the *iCloud* folder in the current tab, but it *does* open the *iCloud* folder rather than the `"Mobile Documents"` folder:

```
tell application "System Events" to open folder "~/Library/Mobile Documents"
```

I'm not familiar with any method that will give you the best of both worlds.  It seems that you either must settle for the `"Mobile Documents"` folder opening in the tab you want; or a new tab being created to open the folder you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy.
Create an alias of the iCloud folder and place that on the local hard drive then use Apple Script to open the alias and that opens the iCloud folder:
set itemPath to "Macintosh HD:Users:username:folder:alias_name"
tell application "Finder"
set theItem to item itemPath
if (class of theItem) is folder then activate
open theItem
end tell